# Curl of a noise field on a sphere

Tags: curl, noise, divergence-theorem

### Problem

Hey people. I'm currently working on a small approximation of a fluid simulation on a sphere based on curl noise. The math behind that is based on [this paper](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Erbridson/docs/bridson-siggraph2007-curlnoise.pdf), which notes that because the curl of a field is divergence free, which should hold for the velocity of an incompressible fluid. To do the simulation I am trying to create such a velocity field tangent to the sphere, so in $\hat{\theta}$ and $\hat{\phi}$ direction (I use $\hat{\phi}$ 0 at the north pole).

However, when I calculate a velocity field like this and move a series of particles over the sphere, the field does not seem divergence free as I end up with a lot of spirals.

[image]

Why is this? I would presume that if one takes the derivative of the noise in the tangent direction on the sphere, this would also be divergence free.

### Math

This part is just the math I use to calculate the curl for reference *

Now, I have a noise function which gives for each point in 3D the value of F and a vector with the partial derivatives

$$ \nabla_{cart} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{dF}{dx}\\ \frac{dF}{dy}\\ \frac{dF}{dz} \end{bmatrix}$$

What I currently do is project the partial derivatives onto the sphere and then calculate the curl based on that. So I first calculate the tangent vectors as

$$\hat{\phi}_{cart}= \begin{bmatrix} cos(\theta)cos(\phi)\\ sin(\theta)cos(\phi)\\-sin(\phi) \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\hat{\theta}_{cart}=sin(\phi)\begin{bmatrix}-sin(\theta)\\ cos(\theta)\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Where the length of $\hat{\theta}_{cart}$ is scaled with $sin(\phi)$ to compensate for the difference in distance in world space at the poles.
Then I project the partial derivatives onto this to get

$$\nabla_{proj} = \begin{bmatrix} \hat{\theta}_{cart} \cdot \nabla_{cart} \\ \hat{\phi}_{cart} \cdot \nabla_{cart} \end{bmatrix} $$

I calculate the curl as

$$ \nabla \times \textbf{F}= \begin{bmatrix} - \hat{\phi}_{cart} \cdot \nabla_{cart} \\\hat{\theta}_{cart} \cdot \nabla_{cart}  \end{bmatrix} $$

I then use this curl to move the particles in tangent space.

Does anything stand out here as incorrect?